# Android. Layout. Wrap text around layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

How can I achieve this behavior?

```
0101010101010101
1______________0
0|            |1
1|  My Layout |0
0--------------1
1010101010101010
```

I've tried to make an 9.patch, but it only stretches image.
Also I've tried to create a bitmap with:

```
android:tileMode="repeat"
```

But this has unpredictable behavior with various screen width.

Thanks